# Python Selenium clicking button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to create something of my own but I can't manage to find how to click on this button...

I'm trying to find the way to click there but I tried a lot of things and each time I get :
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"commit"}`

I tried the simple and hard one, but nothing worked...

```
driver.find_element_by_name('commit').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//fieldset[@id='add-remove-buttons']/input").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='add-remove-buttons']/input").click() # this one is the xpath of the inspection with chrome
```

if you have an idea thanks for the help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQBsJ.png)

Comment: Try running your code without the first line. From the error message, it looks like that one's throwing an error. Do the other lines cause errors?

Comment: Locator looks fine, try adding some wait before the click.

Comment: i didn't understand, (i don't use all the 3 at the same time but only one).
@musikreck i use only one but i get an error each time...

Comment: AHHHH It worked when i wait!!! THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait for the element and then use one of your find_by_element methods.

For example:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds
element = driver.find_element_by_id("add-remove-buttons")
```

Comment: IT WORKS WHEN I WAIT! thanks mate! beeing on this error all day